# Cant Add Item to Array of Structs in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I cant add an item to array of struct and couldnt figure out why. This is how it looks like: Struct:

```
typedef struct node
{
    char *data;
    int count;
};
```

Array initialization:

```
struct node* list = malloc(100 * sizeof(struct node));
```

Add Part: (buffer is read from file)

```
fscanf( fp, "%s", &buffer);

list[ index].data = (char*)malloc(strlen( buffer));
strcpy( list[ index].data, buffer);
list[ index].count = 0;
index++;
```

Comment: Standard Warning : Please [do not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family.

Comment: 1) what makes you feel you `can't add`? 2) did you initialize `index`? 3) always check the return value of `fscanf()`. 4) instead of `malloc()` and `strcpy()`, you can use `strdup()` directly.

Comment: Note that you don't allocate enough space for data. `strlen` doesn't include nul character, so you should add `+1`.

Comment: same problem with strlen( buffer) + 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems with your code

1. It's unsafe, using `fscanf()` like that is dangerous. You need to tell `fscanf()` to stop reading after a certain ammount of characters to avoid buffer overflow, so for example

   ```
   char buffer[100];
   if (fscanf(fp, "%99s", buffer) != 1)
       doNot_Try_to_copy_buffer_itWasNotInitialized();
   ```
2. You are passing the address of `buffer` to `fscanf()` which is wrong, why? depends on how you declared `buffer`, if you declared it like

   ```
   char buffer;
   ```

   it's wrong because you willll have space for just one character and almost surely your program will invoke undefined behavior, if you declared it as

   ```
   char buffer[SOME_REASONABLE_SIZE];
   ```

   then the problem is that `sizeof(buffer[0]) != sizeof(&buffer[0])` and hence pointer arithmetic will be a problem inside `fscanf()`.
3. It's wrong, you are allocating the wrong ammount for the `data` field. A c string consists of a sequence of non-`nul` bytes followed by a `nul` byte, you are allocating space for the non-`nul` part only since `strlen()` returns the number of non--`null` characters, `strcpy()` will copy the `'\0'` and hence your program will invoke undefined behavior, the correct way of duplicating a string is

   ```
   size_t length = strlen(buffer);
   list[index].data = malloc(1 + length);
   if (list[index].data != NULL)
       memcpy(list[index].data, buffer, 1 + length);
   ```

   note that i've used `memcpy()` because the `length` was alreadly computed with `strlen()` so I don't want `strcpy()` searching for the `'\0'` again.

Your code is unsafe because you ignore the return value of the functions you use, which can lead to undefined behavior.

**Note**: As mentioned in comments, casting `void *` in c is discouraged and unnecessary, and most c programmers don't appreciate that for the issues mentioned in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) posted by @[SouravGhosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2173917/sourav-ghosh).

Comment: @user694733 I will add as much detail as possible. Is it Ok now?